# Rails time_select custom behavior edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with a `time_select` input field. I am manipulating the data in the controller and storing as integer.

In the view

```
<%= f.label :duration %>
<%= f.time_select :duration, {}, { class: 'form-control time-select' }%>
```

In the controller

```
def create
  @task = Task.new(task_params)
  @hours = (params[:task]['duration(4i)']).to_i
  @minutes = (params[:task]['duration(5i)']).to_i
  @task.duration = @hours*60 + @minutes

  respond_to do |format|
    if @task.save
      format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def edit
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  @task['duration(4i)'] = (@task.duration / 60).to_s
  @task['duration(5i)'] = (@task.duration % 60).to_s
end
```

It works for the `create`, but not for the `edit`. I am getting

> can't write unknown attribute `duration(4i)`

Comment: Well that error means that you want to set an attribute on your model that isn't defined.

Comment: Why you don't do the same in the edit action? Or just extract that logic in a private method and call it from the 2 actions.

Comment: @BarnaKovacs thank you for your answer. The attribute is not from the model, is an attribute that `time_select` creates on the view. The problem is that I am not able to set anything on the `time_select` except the current time.

Comment: If you want to set a non-database mapped attribute, just use `attr_accessor`.